# Deriving the expression for $\mathbb{E}|X-Y|^{\alpha}$, $\alpha > 1$, using CDF's $F,G$ and joint $H$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value

Assume that $X$, $Y$ are random variables with joint distribution function $H$ and their respective marginals $F$ and $G$.

I'm trying to show that, for $\alpha > 1$:
$$
\begin{array} \mathbb{E}|X-Y|^{\alpha} &= \alpha (\alpha -1)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x} [G(y) - H(x,y)](x-y)^{\alpha - 2}dydx \\&~~~+~ \alpha (\alpha -1)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{y}[F(x)-H(x,y)](y-x)^{\alpha-2}dxdy
\end{array}$$

Here we know that

$$ E|X-Y|^{\alpha} = \int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|x-y|^{\alpha} \text{d}H(x,y)$$

Any hints/ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: "Any hints/ideas would be appreciated!" The RHS obviously stems from the decomposition $$E(|X-Y|^a)=E((X-Y)^a;X>Y)+E((Y-X)^a;Y>X)$$ and from a double integration by parts in each expectation written in terms of $H$. Can you go further?

Comment: @Did thanks! The first part is clear, but I don't really understand how do we properly get from $dH(x,y)$ to $dxdy$, and why/how do we (seem to) take a second derivative (judging from $\alpha (\alpha - 1)$ and $(x-y)^{\alpha-2}$).

Comment: Both your questions have the same answer, which is that you start from a second derivative of $H$.

Comment: @Did ah, integration by parts, understood this differently at first read. Thanks, I think I got it.